# OpenWRT settings to block access to devices in separate local subnet

Tags: networking, router, openwrt

I have a situation in which I have to create an isolated subnet that has Internet access through another subnet.
The picture might show it more clearly.

```
                                  192.168.5.1
                    LAN               LAN
Internet  +----------+       +----------+      +--------+
     <----+ Router 1 +-------+ Router 2 +------+Device 2|
          | No access|       | OpenWRT  |      |        |
          +------+---+       +----------+      +--------+
              LAN|          WAN                192.168.5.5
                 |       192.168.1.20
            +----+---+
            |Device 1|
            |        |
            +--------+
         192.168.1.50-100
```

I need `Device 2` not to have any access to any device on the 192.168.1.0 network, but still have Internet access.

I can't touch `Router 1` and this needs to be achieved by settings on `Router 2`.

The default settings in `/etc/config/firewall` forward everything from LAN to WAN, which results in Device 1 being able to ping Device 2.

I have tried to limit this with the following rule:

```
config rule                                 
        option src lan                                     
        option dest wan                         
        option dest_ip 192.168.1.50            
        option target REJECT
```

But that didn't do the trick.
Can you please point me in a correct direction?

Besides setting firewall settings, could this (conceptually)
 be hacked by static routing by setting all the routes to 
`192.168.1.0/24` to some fake point?

Comment: So “I have a situation in which I have to create an isolated subnet that has Internet access through another subnet.” you want this isolated network to have internet access because that sentence contradicts “I need "Device 2" not to have any access to any device in the 192.168.1.0 network, but still have Internet access.” So which is it?  Edit your question

Comment: There is networking se too. Also first picture is not clear to me.

Comment: @Ramhound `Device 2` not being able to directly access any of the other devices on `192.168.1.0` doesn't prevent `Router 2` to correctly route packets designated for Internet.

Comment: Will be migrating this to Networking SE, didn't know about it. Update: Opted not to. There isn't an `openWRT` tag there which is the essential tag to describe the question. @marshalcraft Please say what isn't clear and I'll update.

Comment: Please label the network interfaces in your drawing. Is it correct that Router_1 only has _one_ "lan" interface handling both subnets at the same time?

Comment: @grawity Yes. I don't know how it's internally labeled or defined, but it's an ISP router providing a single subnet with Internet access.

Comment: @TheMeaningfulEngineer Sure it does, the fact I am saying something, should illustrate how weird that sounds.  In order to not allow Router 2’s subnet from reaching Router 1’s subnet you would need to modify the configuration of Router 1’

Comment: @Ramhound Why can't Router 2 drop all the packages on the LAN interface that have source or destination IP from subnet `192.168.1.0`? All the packages designated or originated from Device 2 must go through it.

Comment: Sorry maybe I lack necessary experience but incomprehensible to me.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by a possible hack with static routes. Can you explain your possible scenario a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you do assignment of network subnets based on number of bits. For example, from 192.158.1.64 to 192.158.1.128. Your rule however should block the .50 address. If you need to block a subnet, add the number of bits like in the example below:

```
config rule
    option name     example rule
    option src      lan
    option family   ipv4
    option proto    all
    option dest     wan
    option dest_ip  192.168.1.64/26
    option target   REJECT
```

In your case: I would probably block the complete 192.168.0/24 network.